# the meaning of pun

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-play

A girl posted a photo of her with her friends in facebook captioned as "We are so sweet."
So I thought of commenting in the photo as: If you are really so sweet, I want to taste both of you. Also with a hash tag at the end as punintended.

So I am confused what I am creating is really pun or not. If this is not pun, will somebody clearly explain me the meaning of pun?

Comment: It's more stalker than humorous, tbh. It is a pun, but not one in particularly good taste <— see, *that* was a pun ;) A pun is really any kind of word-play joke, based on similarity of spelling, or having 2 different ways to read the sentence.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you made a pun. A pun is a form of word-play in which a word or phrase is used simultaneously for two of its meanings, or similar-sounding or similar-looking words are exploited for a double meaning. Both meanings make sense, at least somewhat, in the same sentence.

In your pun, your friends used the word **sweet** to mean having a pleasant and kind personality, and your response switched to the meaning of having a pleasant flavor like that of sugar.

Here are a few puns by, or at least attributed to, Groucho Marx, one of the best English-language punsters of all time:

> Time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.
>
> Anyone who says he can see through women is missing a lot.
>
> You can leave in a huff. Or you can leave in a minute and a huff.
>
> Everyone must believe in something. I believe I'll have another beer.
>
> Outside of a dog, a book is man's best friend. Inside of a dog, it's too dark to read.

Most successful puns are quick and spontaneous: unplanned, they fit the situation well and they aren't funny if retold later. And most successful puns play off of a familiar phrase, not just a word on its own: "flies like an arrow", "leave in a huff", "a minute and a half", etc.

Most puns, however, make people groan, so I'll stop there. Hopefully that's enough that you can see what the concept is.

Comment: "War only determines who's left, not who's right".

Comment: _If you're not part of the solution, you're part of the precipitate_ (my favorite chemistry pun).